# how do I prove standardizing a normally distributed random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

1. Let X be a random variable of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Use the properties of expectation to show that
   $$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$
   has mean 0 and variance 1.
2. Let Z be a random variable of mean 0 and variance 1. Show that 
   $$X=\sigma Z+\mu$$
   has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I think I have to use $f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}}$ to help me prove this but I have no idea where to start? I know what expectation is and how to calculate it but which properties specifically is the question talking about?

Comment: I think you should use that $E(aX+b) = aE(X)+b$ and similar properties for the variance (which can be derived from this linearity property of $E$.) That means you e.g. have to show that $E(Z) = 0$ an similarly that the variance of $Z$ is $1$

Comment: There is no mention in the question of the hypothesis that the random variables involved are "normally distributed" and the solution does not depend on this hypothesis. A typo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to use PDFs.

1. Since you're only allowed to use properties of expectation, then
   $$E[Z] = E\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right] = \frac{1}{\sigma}\left[E[X] -   
   \mu\right] = \frac{1}{\sigma}[\mu-\mu] = 0.$$
   Then for the variance
   \begin{align*}
   \text{Var}[Z^2] &= E[Z^2]-E^2[Z] \\
   &= E\left[\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] - 0^2\\
   &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left[E[X^2]-2\mu E[X] +\mu^2\right] \\
   &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}[\{E[X^2]-E^2[X]\} + E^2[X]-2\mu E[X]+\mu^2]\\
   &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}[\{\text{Var}[X]\}+\mu^2-2\mu^2+\mu^2]\\
   &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}[\sigma^2 +0] \\
   &= 1.
   \end{align*}
2. Similar as 1.

   ---

Addendum: If $X,Y$ (not necessarily independent) are random variables and $a,b, c$ are some constants, then the properties it is referring to are

- Scaling:
  $$E[cX] =cE[X].$$
- Addition: 
  $$E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y].$$
  Then $$E[aX+bY+c] = aE[X]+bE[Y]+ c.$$
  The instructions imply that you should be familiar with this by now.

Answer (score 4):

For question 1, you cans use $E[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}]=E[\frac{X}{\sigma}]-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}=0$.
For the variance, use the variance properties: $Var(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})=Var(\frac{X}{\sigma}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})=Var(\frac{X}{\sigma})=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}Var(X)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}=1$.

Question 2 can be answered in a similar manner.

Comment: From the wording of the question (use properties of expectation) maybe for variance one is expected to use the definition of variance as $E((X-\mu)^2)$.